# Alternate preprocessing method to TypeDecorator in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I am using `sqlalchemy.types.TypeDecorator` to preprocess a text field before insertion into a database. It works great except when I am using the `like` expression with a comparator that contains percentages (e.g. `User.name.like('%bar%')`) because the percentages are stripped by the `process_bind_param()` before the query is executed.

This makes me think that a `TypeDecorator` is not the correct approach to implement preprocessing directives. Is there either:

1. An alternate way in SQLAlchemy to preprocess a column? (like a [validator](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_attributes.html?highlight=validate#sqlalchemy.orm.validates)?)
2. Or maybe a way to explicitly bypass `process_bind_param` when executing a query?
3. Or is the workaround I am using (at the end of this post) -- to just use a direct SQL query and bypass the ORM -- the only option?

Here is a minimal implementation of the augmented type:

```
import re
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Text
import sqlalchemy.types as types
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

class AlphaOnlyText(types.TypeDecorator):
    """Replaces everything that's not A-Za-z or space with nothing."""
    impl = types.Text
    def process_bind_param(self, text, dialect):
        return None if text is None else re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z\-\s]', '' , text.strip())


Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'User'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(AlphaOnlyText, unique=True)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User(name='{}')>".format(self.name)
```

Here's code to demonstrate working insertions and queries:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

# Create the database
engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

# Add a row
session.add(User(name='foobar'))

# Query the row
session.query(User).filter_by(name=='foobar').all()
# [<User(name='foobar')>]
```

Here is where it fails -- when I use the `like` expression, the column's `process_bind_param` is run, stripping out the percentages before adding the filter to the query:

```
filter = User.name.like('%bar%')
filter.compile().params
# {'name_1': '%bar%'}  <-- The '%' are still here

session.query(User).filter(filter).all()
# Nothing. (Percent symbols are stripped, so '%bar%' ==> 'bar'.)
#   If your engine was created with `echo=True`
#   you can see this directly in the logging statements
```

If I bypass the ORM I can get what I want via direct SQL, but I don't want to require users to go this route.

```
query_template = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE name LIKE :nm;"
session.execute(query_template, {'nm':'%bar%'}).fetchall()
# [(1, 'foobar')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1, to use a [validator](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_attributes.html?highlight=validate#sqlalchemy.orm.validates), is correct. The `TypeDecorator` is more for actually modifying the type of the data -- e.g. pickling something to store it into the database as a string and the unpickling back to a class, seamlessly, for the user.

The `@validates` decorator in this case is performing a validation on data of the same type. Instead of rejecting/flagging/logging unacceptably formatted data (probably the intended primary use case of validation), the function of your validator is to convert unacceptable data of the same type into acceptable data.

Here's the code:

```
import re
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Text
#import sqlalchemy.types as types  ## Don't need this anymore
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import validates  ## This one for the validator

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base)
    __tablename__ = 'User'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text, unique=True)

    @validates("name")
    def alpha_only(self, key, value):
        return None if value is None else re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z\-\s]', '' , value.strip())

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User(name='{}')>".format(self.name)
```